# City Area onchange in magento2

Tags: javascript, php, magento, magento2

I am using **magento 2.1.0**. I created two dropdown on customer registration form ,where the data is fetching from database.

There are **two databases** :

1. **city** database which contain `city_id` and `city column`.
2. send is **area** table which contain `area_id`, `city_id` and `area column`.

on frontend data is sucessfully fetch, and even onchange is also working on city.

**City dropdown:**

```
 <select name="city" onchange="getArea()" id="city">

        <?php  
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                           $model = $objectManager->create('/city')->serviceCity();
            foreach ($model as $d)
            {  ?>

            <option id="<?php echo $d['city_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $d['city_id']; ?>"><?php echo $d['city']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>

            </select>
```

**Area dropdown:**

```
   <div class="field area required">
            <label for="area" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                    echo __('Area') ?></span></label>
            <select name="area" id="area">
            <?php  
            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                           $model = $objectManager->create('\Area')->serviceArea();
            foreach ($model as $a)
            {  ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $a['area']; ?>"><?php echo $a['area']; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>

            </select>
        </div>
```

**Onchange script:**

```
 <script>

function getArea(){
alert(document.getElementById('city').value);
}
 </script>
```

**Now my question is**, what should I do, when I change the city, in second dropdown related area will display only?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to used ajax to archive your requirement.

Comment: But before calling that ajax, i have to post some data also, may be through controller. That exactly i want to know, how to do that

Comment: You need to pass selected city_id in ajax request and take all area based on passed city Id. And result return by ajax need to fillup in area dropdown.

Comment: can you please give me some coding hint

Comment: Please somebody tell me, how parameter should i pass in controller